# How to replace a list with first element of list in pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df`, which look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Harry', 'Sam', 'Raj', 'Jamie', 'Rupert'],
                   'Country':['USA', "['USA', 'UK', 'India']", "['India', 'USA']", 'Russia', 'China']})

Name           Country

Harry          USA
Sam            ['USA', 'UK', 'India']
Raj            ['India', 'USA']
Jamie          Russia
Rupert         China
```

Some values in `Country` column are list, and I want to replace those list with the first element in the list, so that it will look like this:

```
Name           Country

Harry          USA
Sam            USA
Raj            India
Jamie          Russia
Rupert         China
```

Comment: Those are not lists but strings, are you sure of the provided data?

Comment: Yes, these are strings, it looks like a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have strings, you could use a regex here:

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.extract('((?<=\[["\'])[^"\']*|^[^"\']+$)')
```

output (as a new column for clarity):

```
     Name                 Country Country2
0   Harry                     USA      USA
1     Sam  ['USA', 'UK', 'India']      USA
2     Raj        ['India', 'USA']    India
3   Jamie                  Russia   Russia
4  Rupert                   China    China
```

regex:

```
(             # start capturing
(?<=\[["\'])  # if preceded by [" or ['
[^"\']*       # get all text until " or '
|             # OR
^[^"\']+$     # get whole string if it doesn't contain " or '
)             # stop capturing
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have string you could use [`Series.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) in order to remove '`]'` or `'['` and then use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to convert all rows to list ,after that we could use `.str` accesor

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.strip('[|]').str.split(',')\
                             .str[0].str.replace("'", "")


     Name Country
0   Harry     USA
1     Sam     USA
2     Raj   India
3   Jamie  Russia
4  Rupert   China
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```py
import ast
def changeStringList(value):
  try:
    myList = ast.literal_eval(value)
    return myList[0]
  except:
    return value
df["Country"] = df["Country"].apply(changeStringList)
df
```

##### Output

|  | Name | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Harry | USA |
| 1 | Sam | USA |
| 2 | Raj | India |
| 3 | Jamie | Russia |
| 4 | Rupert | China |

Note that, by using the `changeStringList` function, we try to reform the string list to an interpretable list of strings and return the first value. If it is not a list, then it returns the value itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import ast
df['Country'] = df['Country'].where(df['Country'].str.contains('[', regex=False), '[\'' + df['Country'] + '\']').apply(ast.literal_eval).str[0]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     Name Country
0   Harry     USA
1     Sam     USA
2     Raj   India
3   Jamie  Russia
4  Rupert   China
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex solution.

```
import re

tempArr = []
for val in df["Country"]:
    if val.startswith("["): 
        val = re.findall(r"[A-Za-z]+",val)[0]
        tempArr.append(val)
    else: tempArr.append(val)

df["Country"] = tempArr

df

     Name Country
0   Harry     USA
1     Sam     USA
2     Raj   India
3   Jamie  Russia
4  Rupert   China
```